# How do i remove the empty or null value in the options fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove the empty or null from the options array field array data in javascript

[image]

Comment: You want to remove it when rendering out the data or remove it directly from the data itself?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?msclkid=d07e0016cf6f11ec81c2c3d4b9d5b0dd) with some code and an expected output.

Comment: what is an empty value? undefined or null?

Comment: You want them removed from the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript [array filter.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
arr.forEach((item) => {
    if(Array.isArray(item.options)) {
       item.options = item.options.filter((option) => option != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will break as `options` is not always an array.